# How can I pass nested for loops variable from one function to another?

Tags: typescript, parameter-passing, nested-loops

I am using nested for loop in my function. I am trying to pass variable `i` and variable `j` whole as an object to another function, but it throws an error.

```
public getProductCodes(
   productEvent,
   result,
   messagePublishService: MessagePublishService,
 ) {
   const splitCodes = productEvent.productCodes.split(',');


   for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
     for (let j = 0; j < result[i].products.length; j++) {
       if (
         productEvent.productCodes.length !== 0 &&
         productEvent.productCodes !== undefined
       ) {
         this.publishProductCode(
           messagePublishService,
           splitCodes,
           result[i],result[i].products[j],        -------> This is what I am trying to pass it as an object (Not individual variable)
           source,
         );
       } else {
         console.log('No data found');
         return;
       }
     }
   }
 }

 public publishProductCode(
   messagePublishService,
   splitCodes,
   result[i],           
   result[i].products[j],
   source,
 ) {
   for (let k = 0; k < splitCodes.length; k++) {
     if (result[i].products[j].productCode === splitCodes[k]) {
       console.log(
         'Product Codes: ' +
           result[i].products[j].productCode +
           ' Country : ' +
           result[i].country +
           ' Language : ' +
           result[i].language,
       );
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: What is the value of the `splitCodes` in function call?
What do you mean in `   result[i], result[i].products[j],` in `publishProductCode` definition ?

Comment: result[i].products[j] is the value I am trying to access with nested for loops and pass it on to publishProductCode method

Comment: Function definition don't see the `i`, or `j`, You should only define new property name in it like the current answer

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps replace this:

```
public publishProductCode(
   messagePublishService,
   splitCodes,
   result[i],           
   result[i].products[j],
   source,
 ) {
```

with this:

```
public publishProductCode(
   messagePublishService,
   splitCodes,
   result,           
   resultProducts,
   source,
 ) {
```

And then replace the references to `result[i]` and `result[i].products[j]` with `result` and `resultProducts` accordingly within `publishProductCode`.